# How to use cvLoadImage to load to OpenCV Window?

Tags: opencv

I have the image file on hard disk.

I use "cvLoadImage" to load it and display it on OpenCV's Window. Although this file exists, but, I get a blank window. I can't resolve this problem.

Comment: Can you post some code? Also, what is the error code?

Comment: Do you get any error pop-up or is the window just blank?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code that does you want to do :

```
IplImage * image = cvLoadImage("yourpath", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

cvNamedWindow("Window name");
cvShowImage("Window name", image);
cvWaitKey(); //To wait until you pressed a key

cvReleaseImage(&image);
```

Tell me what error message do you get (if any).

Answer (score 0):

You need to simply put "waitKey(1);" after you showImage(XXX);.

That will let computer have a breathing time to display which image you want to show.